# How To Make A Client Side Chat Mod In Minecraft Using Python

Tags: python, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I know when you wanted to make a **Minecraft Mod** your typically choose **Java** but I only know python and noticed these

- [CodeMage](https://www.Minecraftforum.Net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/wip-mods/2494569-codemage-python-programming-in-minecraft)
- [RaspberryJamMod](https://pypi.Python.Org/pypi/raspberryjammod)

However the above doesn't have enough documentations for me

**My Question : Is there an python api for Minecraft that makes it possible for the following**

- get your Minecraft username
- get the peoples in game name into a list
- display chat messages to your own client side Minecraft
- adding your own commands example "/L"
- make commands for the player example doing "/L" would make the player submit "/Lobby"

I only need to add a simple command "/Highest" that gets the username from players in game then make a http requests and tell the user whos the highest stat in that game

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please keep in mind that this site is not meant for looking for software or product recommendations. For more info, look over [ask].

Comment: Try [searching GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=minecraft+language%3Apython&type=Repositories).